# ffmpeg_extract_subclip fails to trim some videos

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg

I am using `ffmpeg_extract_subclip(video_name, start-9, start, targetname=target_name)` to trim a 9s video.

The `start` (`int`) variable comes from a json file:

```
start = b_info_list[elem+1]["start_time"]
delta_1 = dt.strptime(start, "%H:%M:%S.%f") - dt.strptime("", "")
start = int(delta_1.total_seconds())
```

The same exact code is working for most of the videos and their json counterparts, but not working for some of them only. So I'm assuming there's nothing wrong with variables `start` which is always `>= 10` and `video_name`, `target_name`.

The error log is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data/video_trim.py", line 324, in <module>
    main()
  File "data/video_trim.py", line 316, in main
    norm_symp_act_videos(f)
  File "data/video_trim.py", line 235, in norm_symp_act_videos
    ffmpeg_extract_subclip(video_name, start-9, start, targetname=target_name)
  File "/home/office/anaconda3/envs/env_2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_tools.py", line 41, in ffmpeg_extract_subclip
    subprocess_call(cmd)
  File "/home/office/anaconda3/envs/env_2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/moviepy/tools.py", line 54, in subprocess_call
    raise IOError(err.decode('utf8'))
OSError: ffmpeg version 4.2.2-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/office/data/video_05.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2021-10-13T04:33:45.000000Z
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:02:00.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3149 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 3148 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-10-13T04:33:45.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      timecode        : 01:00:00:00
    Stream #0:1(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-10-13T04:33:45.000000Z
      handler_name    : TimeCodeHandler
      timecode        : 01:00:00:00
[mp4 @ 0x62a7600] You requested a copy of the original timecode track so timecode metadata are now ignored
[mp4 @ 0x62a7600] Could not find tag for codec none in stream #1, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

The function looks like this:

```
def ffmpeg_extract_subclip(filename, t1, t2, targetname=None):
    """ Makes a new video file playing video file ``filename`` between
        the times ``t1`` and ``t2``. """
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if not targetname:
        T1, T2 = [int(1000*t) for t in [t1, t2]]
        targetname = "%sSUB%d_%d.%s" % (name, T1, T2, ext)
    
    cmd = [get_setting("FFMPEG_BINARY"),"-y",
           "-ss", "%0.2f"%t1,
           "-i", filename,
           "-t", "%0.2f"%(t2-t1),
           "-map", "0", "-vcodec", "copy", "-acodec", "copy", targetname]
    
    subprocess_call(cmd)
```

I looked for the similar issues, but solutions to them are in command format which I don't understand. Is there anyone who can help solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Please avoid obfuscation, and post a reproducible code sample. Please remove all the parts of the code that are not relevant - you may keep one line. Replace `get_setting("FFMPEG_BINARY")` with the value. Replace `"%0.2f"%t1` with the number, replace `"%0.2f"%(t2-t1)` with the number, Replace `targetname` with a string.

Comment: @Rotem I haven't written the function myself it's already there.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Are you trying to say that you don't know programming?

Comment: no, All I am trying to say is that I used this function `ffmpeg_extract_subclip` to trim videos, but, this very function is working for some of my videos and not working for others. To clarify, I just posted the original function to show what means what. I imported it as `from moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools import ffmpeg_extract_subclip`.

Comment: Please use the debugger, place a breakpoint in `subprocess_call(cmd)`, copy `cmd` as a list, and add it to your post.

Comment: According to the error message the issue is related to "Timecode Media" `Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)`. it looks like "Timecode Media" is not well supported by FFmpeg. According to the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65153578/invalid-data-stream-in-media-could-not-be-discarded-by-ffmpeg-why-is-it-staying), adding `-write_tmcd false` may help. According to the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51354696/ffmpeg-concat-and-preserve-metadata-streams) there is an issue with GoPro, solved by `-copy_unknown -tag:2 gpmd`. I can't find a relevant video sample.